# How to separate a string of integers and convert to letters

Tags: python, string, integer

I want to turn a 3 or 4 character string of integers into a 3 or 4 character string of letters using the number letter conversion offered in the [Dominic System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominic_system). This was going to be my first project not following a tutorial or book, and I'm already stuck.

An example would be turning the string 723 into GBC, or 1032 into AOCB. I can only think of making the input (the number) and turning it into a list, but I do not know where to go from there.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually remarkably easy in Python:

```
# Import the function
from string import maketrans
# Set up a translation to the Dominic system
transtab = maketrans('1234567890', 'ABCDESGHNO')
# You could input this somehow
my_num = 9876
# Convert number to string and translate it
print str(my_num).translate(transtab)
```

And to reverse this:

```
# Set up a translation from the Dominic system
rev_transtab = maketrans('ABCDESGHNO', '1234567890')
# You could input this somehow
my_string = 'ONHG'
# Translate string and convert to number
print int(my_string.translate(rev_transtab))
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of length 10. Each index in the array will hold the associated letter. Then, iterate over your string, grab each digit, and use that as an index to the array to find the associated letter.

```
dominic=[]
dominic.append( "A")
dominic.append( "B")
dominic.append( "C")
dominic.append( "D")
dominic.append( "E")
dominic.append( "F")
dominic.append( "G")
dominic.append( "H")
dominic.append( "I")
dominic.append( "J")

convertMe = "44556";
final = ""
for digit in convertMe:
    final = final + dominic[int(digit)]
print final
```

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried? You can create a dictionary that maps numbers to letters, for example.

```
>>> string_of_ints = '1234'
>>> num_mapping = {
'1': 'A',
'2': 'B', ...
}
>>> list_of_letters = map(num_mapping,[x for x in string_of_ints])
>>> list_of_letters
['A','B','C','D']
```

map() allows you to input a list of keys into a dictionary and output the values from the dictionary.

Finally you can reduce the list back into a string using reduce:

```
>>> reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,list_of_letters)
'ABCD'
```